# Windows 10 fails to boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

I had a working dual boot configuration of win8 and Ubuntu 15.10 when I decided to delete win8 and install win10 that's where the problem started. After wiping out win8 and installing win10 I thought a simple boot repair through a ubuntu LIVECD would be enough to boot both my OSes but to my surprise after running boot repair and after it displayed the boot repair successful msg I was unable to boot into windows, as I clicked on the windows loader on dev/sda1, I encountered the purple screen of death
. After that I deleted all the three partitions of Ubuntu (root, swap and home) and reinstalled it still no luck.. For the very first time after reinstalling I was able to boot into windows but when I tried it for the second time the same problem resurfaced. Sometimes the screen reads `Windows failed to start, a recent hardware or software change might be the problem` and other times it just freezes on the purple screen.. Any insights would be appreciated.. Here is my boot info which I generated after reinstalling Ubuntu [boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23955263/)
. I have already tried replacing the `chainloader=chainloader+1`of the windows 10 menu entry with,`ntldr ($root) /bootmgr` but to no avail..

Edit: I think I might have zeroed in on the problem. The problem is whenever I press the power button manually for more than 30 secs I am able to boot into windows 10 on grub without any glitch but when I restart or shut down my windows and then power on the normal way and try to boot win10, grub hangs and freezes. Also I am able to mount the ntfs partition from nautilus the first time but not in the second time ( I tried to check if really windows hibernation was causing the error, I disabled fast startup on Windows and then tried to repair using `ntfsfix` and removing the `hibfile` using `ntfs-3g` on Ubuntu but it returned with the same problem). Can anybody tell me what is happening or give me any permanent solutions! Also both Ubuntu and Windows10 are installed in legacy mode and secure boot is disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Was Windows 8 pre-installed or had you manually installed? Windows would normally be UEFI/gpt, but your system is now BIOS/MBR. But whether UEFI or BIOS you must have Windows 8 or 10 fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: No windows 8 did not come pre-installed it it was installed in legacy mode as Windows 10 is now and I m pretty sure ubuntu is also installed in

Comment: Regarding the fast start up this might be the problem since I am able to boot into windows after turning off my pc for a long time but even after I tried restarting (and not shut down) windows, I was unable to boot into it for the second time. And also I am unable to mount my ntfs partitions in nautilus (ubuntu) so it is indeed in hibernated state(i think). Any suggestions?

Comment: With UEFI you can always directly boot Windows from UEFI. But if locked up with hibernation, you probably need to use a repair disk to temporarily reinstall the Windows boot loader to MBR, so you can boot Windows. Then use Ubuntu with Boot-Repair or manually add grub back to MBR once Windows fixed. You may regularly have to do that as Windows updates may turn it back on. Check before shutting down Windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: Already tried running boot repair multiple times it didn't help

Comment: Boot-Repair cannot fix most Windows issues. And if Windows fast start up or hibernation is on, Boot-Repair (Linux NTFS driver) may not even see your Windows install. You have to boot into Windows and turn off fast boot, and can only do that with a Windows boot loader in MBR. Then restore grub to allow dual booting. If Boot-Repair does see Windows, then in advanced mode install Windows boot loader, if not use your Windows repair disk or installer's repair console (f8). Or install lilo or syslinux boot loader from Ubuntu as temporary Windows type boot loader.

Comment: As I said, I have already disabled fast boot on Windows then ran a boot repair (boot repair could see windows as I checked in the boot-info file) still it fails to load windows sometimes as I mentioned in my edit

Comment: This is where UEFI is easier as you can always directly boot all installs from UEFI boot menu. With BIOS you only have one MBR to boot from. But you should not have a hiberfile if Windows hibernation & fast start up is really off. And ntfsfix turns on chkdsk flag but does not really run much in the way of fixes. And if chkdsk flag is on, Ubuntu will not mount NTFS to prevent further damage to NTFS. You need to only run chkdsk from Windows and make doubly sure both fast start & hibernation is off. Windows on updates may turn fast start back on, also.